# How to run specific tests for specific parameters in pytest

Tags: pytest

I am developing an automated test suite for a set of slightly different devices. I am using pytest framework. Tests drive the device, and check how it responds.

The device consists of several identical channels, so I would like to utilize pytest parametrize feature, and run tests for every channel. The communication with device channel is pretty complex, so I hide it in a channel fixture (in the code below it just returns a channel name, but in reality it creates a complex object). Instead of using pytest.mark.parametrize I made a parametrized fixture, that creates and runs an object for each channel.

```
channels = ["left", "right"]

@pytest.fixture(scope = 'function', params = channels)
def channel(request):
    id = request.param[0]   # TODO: Create channel object here, return ID for now
    yield id

def test_channel(channel):
    print(channel)
    pass
```

So far so good. But now I need to alter channels list depending on settings - different devices might expose different number of channels, and their names. I need something like

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def channels_list(pytestconfig):
    target_device = pytestconfig.getini('target_device')

    if target_device == "DeviceA":
        return ["left", "right"]
    if target_device == "DeviceB":
        return ["up", "center", "down"]
```

I made it as a fixture in order to leverage pytestconfig infrastructure to be able to define target device either in INI file, or override it through the command line.

But the question is: how to use channels_list fixture to parameterize other fixture (channel)? It says I cannot use fixture functions directly.

Comment: It might be worth thinking of an answer in more of a test design instead of code.
In a lot of cases different devices (channels) need different tests or fixtures, so creating a different TestClass or file will be a better solution, you can use @pytest.mark.DeviceA decorator to run the tests in a more simple way using -m DeviceA

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about this too. However, in my case devices consist of channels. Tests exercise channels - this is where the functionality is located. The device itself is not interesting, and does not provide any functionality. Devices are just an integrating entity,  it just contains certain number of channels, depending on the device type.  So making a fixture for a device would cause a loop on device channels in every test. Anyhow, I found how to make parameterization I need, see an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out how to do parameterize tests depending on configuration file or command line parameter. I also made even more challenging thing: the parameterization list consists of pairs - ID to be used in test, and a human readable name to be shown in the test parameter.

conftest.py:

```
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addini('target_device',       'Name of the target board (options: DeviceA, DeviceB)')


def channels_list(target_device):
    if target_device == "DeviceA":
        return [(1, "left"), (2, "right")]
    if target_device == "DeviceB":
        return [(3, "up"), (4, "center"), (5, "down")]


def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    if "channel_descr" in metafunc.fixturenames:
        target_device = metafunc.config.getini("target_device")
        metafunc.parametrize("channel_descr", channels_list(target_device), ids=lambda x: x[1])
```

Thus everything that uses 'channel_descr' will be parameterized with one of the lists, depending on the target board selected.

But there is more. You can use fixtures in between of creating a list of parameters, and the test to parameterize:

```
class Channel:
    def __init__(self, descr):
        print(f"Create a new channel object: {descr[1]}")
        self.id = descr[0]
        self.name = descr[1]
    

@pytest.fixture(scope = 'function')
def channel(channel_descr):
    return Channel(channel_descr)
```

Finally, the test simply uses the parameterized fixture:

```
def test_any(channel):
    print(channel.id)
```

This test will be executed for all channels in the selected device. Moreover, the test code uses channel ID, while the channel name is used as a human readable name for the parameter.

```
test_test.py::test_any[left] PASSED
test_test.py::test_any[right] PASSED
```

Metafunction stuff can be also used to disable some tests depending on a runtime condition.

conftest.py:

```
def is_good_device(target_device):
    return target_device in ["DeviceA"]


def pytest_collection_modifyitems(config, items):
    target_device = config.getini("target_device")
    for item in items:
        if "good_device" in item.keywords and not is_good_device(target_device):
            item.add_marker(pytest.mark.skip(reason="Not a good device"))
```

tests:

```
@pytest.mark.good_device
def test_good_device(channel):
    print(channel.id)
```

The difference between this approach and standard one is that the condition is calculated in runtime, and the 'is_good_device' function can be non-trivial.

```
test_test.py::test_any[up] PASSED                                                                                                                      [ 16%] 
test_test.py::test_any[center] PASSED                                                                                                                  [ 33%]
test_test.py::test_any[down] PASSED                                                                                                                    [ 50%]
test_test.py::test_good_device[up] SKIPPED (Not a good device)                                                                                         [ 66%]
test_test.py::test_good_device[center] SKIPPED (Not a good device)                                                                                     [ 83%]
test_test.py::test_good_device[down] SKIPPED (Not a good device)                                                                                       [100%]
```